# Hung Glassfish after limited usage, GC?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

I'm working on the following setup:

```
OS         CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
Memory     1024MB
CPU        1 × 2.4 Ghz @ 80%
Glassfish  GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)
```

I'm aware that this is only a small setup with limited memory, though it should suffice.

Here's my problem (I know, there's written a lot about it already):

After some usage my memory seems to clog up. This leads to a hung Glassfish, `meminfo` show something like:

```
MemTotal:        1030772 kB
MemFree:          158488 kB
Buffers:            3204 kB
Cached:            16340 kB
SwapCached:         7100 kB
Active:           413424 kB
Inactive:         410252 kB
```

`top` shows:

```
PID  USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
2380 root      20   0  860m 658m 6028 S 99.8 65.4 170:58.30 java
```

**Conclusion**

My Glassfish server tends to use all resources after a while. I'm not sure as too why the CPU is clogged, though I'm suspecting this has something to do with Garbage Collection.

My question is, how can I prevent this from happening? Should I configure my GC, if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1024MB isn't trivial.  I don't know what your app is doing, but it's a respectable start.

Since Java uses a generational memory model, I'd recommend getting a dynamic picture of all the generations: perm gen, eden, etc.

I like Visual VM, with all the plug-ins installed.  It lets me see memory, threads, CPU, objects in real time.  Try it and see if it'll help you.  More information is what you need.

Comment: Ok, you're saying the given information is not sufficient to point out the real issue here? Will try Visual VM!

Comment: Knowing that memory is consumed isn't enough; it happens over time.  I'd want to know why.  Is your memory inadequate, or do you have a leak in your code?  A profiler can help you figure out the root cause.

Comment: It has taken a while to get VisualVM running due to some high priority requirements. After some testing it seems that my `Heap` keeps on growing while the `PermGen` is restoring just fine.

Comment: keeps growing?  the gc doesn't give you a nice sawtooth?  or does the sawtooth trend up over time?  sounds like you have a memory leak.

Comment: It does after an hour or so. Though I'm not completely convinced yet where my problem is. I'm trying to recreate the hung system (haven't managed to do so yet).

Comment: Move on to the object creation window on Visual VM and see which object is clogging memory.  It might give you a hint.  Look for your packages, not the JVM ones.

Comment: Look for static Maps that you add to but never clean up.  Caches are good candidates.